# Parse and Access below JSON data format from HashMap in Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

Parse and Access below JSON data format from HashMap in Java in order to verify the mapping of keys with their values.

Below is the JSON String:

```
{
    "Inputs": {
        "TSVInput": {
            "ColumnNames": ["Bearing_11", "Bearing_12", "Bearing_21", "Bearing_22", "Bearing_31", "Bearing_32", "Bearing_41", "Bearing_42"],
            "Values": [[0.071, -0.054, 0.015, -0.144, -0.227, 0.012, -0.076, -0.073]]
        }
    },
    "GlobalParameters": {}
}
```

the below source code doesn't do the mapping & giving null value while access a particular filed. I am confused on how to parse this nested JSON data.

```
File file = null;
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullFileName));

                String readLine = "";
                System.out.println("Reading file using Buffered Reader");

               while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        //System.out.println(readLine);
                        String jsonString = readline;

                        //System.out.println(jsonString);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        HashMap<String, Object> myMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
                        System.out.println(myMap.get(1));
}
```

Comment: `myMap` has String keys and you are using `Integer` to access it ? - `myMap.get(1)`

Comment: what values you want to get from json?

Comment: do you want to check if in the hashmap with key "Bearing_11" has 0.071 as value and so on?

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes, I want to check the value against each fields and I have modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bson and bypass hashmap all together.  I am curious as to how people do this with hashmap.

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
 //import org.bson.Document;
```

Load your json

```
 Document root = Document.parse("{ \"Inputs\" : { \"TSVInput\" : { \"ColumnNames\" : [\"Bearing_11\", \"Bearing_12\", \"Bearing_21\", \"Bearing_22\", \"Bearing_31\", \"Bearing_32\", \"Bearing_41\", \"Bearing_42\"], \"Values\" : [[0.071, -0.054, 0.015, -0.144, -0.227, 0.012, -0.076, -0.073]] } }, \"GlobalParameters\" : { } }");
```

You can all your json objects and cast to the appropriate types.

```
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(0)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(1)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(2)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(3)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(4)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(5)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(6)));
 System.out.println(((String)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("ColumnNames")).get(7)));
 System.out.println(((int)((ArrayList)((Document)((Document)root.get("Inputs")).get("TSVInput")).get("Values")).get(0)));
```